# Javascript condition based on Rails variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, constants

I want to set a global constant (in `Rails`) and then depending on that I want to put a condition in a `JavaScript` file (which is included in every page of my app). I also have some Rails dependent code based on this variable.

What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In application_controller.rb

```
def before_filter
  # This variable will be available in all controller actions and views
  @my_global = "testing" 
end
```

In application.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var my_global = "<%= @my_global %>"
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like the neatest way to do it... (I didn't try the gem way)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a global variable like: `window.profileName = 'Shikher';`. Or in case you need several global variables I'd suggest to create a scope:

```
var Globals = {};
Globals.profileName = '<%= @user.profile_name %>';
```

and somewhere else

```
Globals.userId = '<%= @user.id %>';
```

In case you will use it everywhere you can insert the globals defenition right in the layout file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this gem http://github.com/ejschmitt/jsvars to define javascript vars via ruby and then use them in you js